# Node.js Error: require is not defined in clientside js file

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, browserify, require

I have a Javascript file in which I have data that needs to be saved into a Mongoose schema and subsequently inserted into a MongoDB table. The schema is defined in a file in a separate directory so I tried to essentially import it by including the following line at the top of the file:

```
//import schema for sketches
var SketchSchema = require('../schemas/sketch_objs');
```

I then got the error "Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined"
which I found out [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19059580/client-on-node-uncaught-referenceerror-require-is-not-defined) was due to the fact that `require()` doesn't exist on the client-side. As suggested in the answer for that post, I installed Browserify in order to be able to require the schema javascript file.

I couldn't really ascertain the specific usage of Browserify's functionality to achieve this but it seemed from the github readme that something like the following has to be done:

`$ browserify main.js > bundle.js`

where the required files in main.js will be included inside of bundles.js. I tried to doing this for the file that needed to include the schema and successfully generated the new file; however, for some reason when I run the project, I still get the error about require not being defined. Is it supposed to be that the new file generated by Browserify is supposed to be used instead of the old file? **If this isn't the case, what is the correct way to require another js file inside a file on the client side?**

Comment: You can't just call mongodb functions in the browser. You will have to create a layered application with an api (for example a rest service) to store and load your data.

Answer (score 1):

So

- you need browserify to require the JS file CommonJs way.
- I do not think mongoDB is compatible with browserify, FYI, https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/NODE-698

Comment: Well, I'm using Mongoose as an ORM so is there any other way to achieve what I'm trying to do?